# How do i change value of variable by using jQuery UI range Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine I have setInterval

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Hi");
}, 1000);
```

Imagine I have setInterval with that random function which will generate random number each call.

```
setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Hi");
    }, 1000 + Math.random() * 4000);
```

It will call setInterval between 1 to 4 sec

Now all I want is change the value of the integers by using that kind of slider:
https://jsfiddle.net/qetwstkb/

I want to manipulate these values by using the slider. :) 
Couldn't explain it better am not native English speaker, sorry. >_<

Comment: Your question is not clear.  1) Do you want to update the variable based on the slider, or do you want to create the slider based on the variable?  2)  You have a variable `random` with one value, but you are talking about two values.

Comment: Do you want a slider with `min: 5`, `max: 390`, and a variable that is updated based on the value of the slider when the user interacts with the slider?

Comment: Kind of. I want to make slider which will work for delay changing, but it's important for me to have the random function on it.

Comment: `5` and `390` for the min and max values, are fixed amounts.  What do want to do with the random value?

Comment: I've edited the whole question, hope it's understandable now.

Comment: I've edited my answer based on your edited question.  Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! :)

Comment: I actually updated the answer again to return the interval ID and use `clearInterval()` so that you are not setting another `setInterval` function each time the value changes, but instead clear the previous one before setting up the new one.

Comment: Hm, you did a really good job, but the Interval was just an example. So it's not necessary. I wanted to put the value from slider to global variable so I can use that variable inside my other function. And I don't really know how to do it with your example.

Comment: Declare the variables as global variables, and then update them in the `update` function.   (Instead of `var min = ...` do `min  = ...` to update the gloabal `min` variable)

Comment: If it's unclear, you may want to post this as a separate question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149423/discussion-between-hatchling-and-chava-g).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the selected range values, you can use:

```
var min = $("#slider").slider("values")[0];
var max = $("#slider").slider("values")[1];
```

And to execute a callback function when the values change, use the `slide` option.

Once you have the values, you can put those values anywhere, including a `setInterval` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function(){

  var update = function() {
    var min = $("#slider").slider("values")[0];
    var max = $("#slider").slider("values")[1];
    
     var i = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Hi");
    }, min + Math.random() * max);
    
    return i;
  }
  
  var i;
  
  $("#slider").slider({
    values: [1000, 1750],
    min: 500,
    max: 3900,
    step: 0.1,
    slide: function (e, ui) {
      clearInterval(i);
      i = update();
    }
    
  });
  
});

});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
```